Access spark context inside mapPartitions in pyspark
I have a code, written on scala, and I want to use it in pyspark (3.1.1) via Py4J:
jvm = sc._gateway.jvm
heavy_class = jvm.path.to.scala.class.HeavyClass("param1", "param2")

def process(partitionData):
    for row in partitionData:
        rowDict = {"col1": row.col1, "col2": row.col2}
        yield heavy_class.method(rowDict)

df.rdd.mapPartitions(process).toDF(["col3"])

In that case I have an error:
Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

I tried to initiate heavy class inside mapPartitions:
def process(partitionData):
    sparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    jvm = sparkContext._gateway.jvm
    heavy_class = jvm.path.to.scala.class.HeavyClass("param1", "param2")
    for row in partitionData:
        rowDict = {"col1": row.col1, "col2": row.col2}
        yield heavy_class.method(rowDict)

df.rdd.mapPartitions(process).toDF(["col3"])

But in this case I faced another error:
SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.

Tried to set option "spark.executor.allowSparkContext=true", but it has no effect.
Is it possible to serialize objects from py4j or use spark context in mapPartition?

Not exactly a duplicate, but probably helpful: Link

Serializing the HeavyClass won't help because next you may find that some of its dependencies need to be serialized too, etc. etc.
